# How Can I Combine These Multiple MySQL Queries?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a couple of tables where I need to perform some queries. The code looks like this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table1,table2 WHERE table1.item1='$item1' AND table2.item2='1' AND table1.item2=table2.item2";
```

The problem I a have is I have about 25 similar queries to make, the only difference is

```
table2.item2='1'
table2.item2='2'
...
table2.item2='25'
```

What I'd like to be able to do is to write just one query, but still be able to extract the data. I think some sort of loop function (I'm using PHP) should be able to do it, but I haven't been able to come up with one.

Main problem is the numbers 1-25 in my example are not consecutive numbers - they actually look like 204, 208, 465, 646, etc.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you already have a list of `item2` values in hand, then you can use it in `where` clause after `JOIN`. Example `WHERE table1.item1='$item1' AND table2.item2 in ( $csv_of_item2_values )`

Answer (score 0):

use `join`

```
SELECT * FROM table1 t1 join table2 t2
on t1.item2=t2.item2
WHERE t1.item1='$item1' AND 
t2.item2 BETWEEN 1 AND 25
```

Comment: Thank you, Rahatous. The problem though is that t2.item2='1'  is true for only one query, and I have 25 similar ones to make (last one being t2.item2='25'). What I am trying to do is to avoid writing 25 separate queries...

Comment: SELECT * FROM table1 t1 join table2 t2
    on t1.item2=t2.item2
    WHERE t1.item1='$item1' AND 
    t2.item2 BETWEEN 1 AND 25

Comment: try this query @Cucurigu

Comment: Sorry I was not very clear in my initial description, Rahatous - the number sequence is not consecutive, it has 25 numbers but they are more like 204, 208, 465, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use [JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html) to fetch data from multiple tables.

Try this

```
$sql = "";
$sql .= "SELECT * FROM table1 t1 join table2 t2
on t1.item2=t2.item2
WHERE t1.item1='$item1'"; 

for($i = 1; $i<=25; $i++)
    $sql .= " AND t2.item2='$i' ";
```

**Edit:** As per you comment, following is the option you can use.
For simplicity, just take all the values in an array and use foreach to loop through it and form your query.

```
$array = array("204", "208", "465", "646");

foreach($array as $arr)
    $sql .= " AND t2.item2='$arr' ";
```

Comment: Thanks Suyog. This looks promising, I'll give it a try and let you know if it works.

Comment: I forgot to mention though that the numbers 1-25 in my example are not actually consecutive numbers - they actually look like 204, 208, 465, 646, etc. There are a total of 25 such numbers, but they are not consecutive. Any ideas on how to run a loop through such an irregular sequence?

Comment: Thanks again, Suyog, I'll try this.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [MYSQL JOINS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html) it is used to get data from multiple table.